# How to redirect HTTP and HTTPS traffic to custom chain iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking, redirect

I am trying to redirect all output HTTP and HTTPS packets to my custom chain, but it doesn't work

Here is my rules

```
iptables -t nat -N CUSTOMCHAIN
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j CUSTOMCHAIN
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j CUSTOMCHAIN
```

But this doesn't work, when I try to use `wget` or `curl` like that
`wget somesite.com` it doesn't get redirected.

Here is the statistic output.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 1418 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 CUSTOMCHAIN   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
2        0     0 CUSTOMCHAIN   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
3        0     0 CUSTOMCHAIN   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
4        0     0 CUSTOMCHAIN   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
5        0     0 CUSTOMCHAIN   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
```

Please help what could be wrong ?

**UPDATE**

Could someone please explain when `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j CUSTOMCHAIN` this rule will be triggered ? Is only applied for incoming packages ?

Comment: Is iptables running in the webserver or in a router? The `nat` table will only be applied if the packet is going to be routed, if the connection is going to terminate in the server running iptables it won't "pass" through the nat table so your rules will be ignored.

Comment: @PabloMartinez thank you for the answer, could you explain please, what does terminate mean in this case, when I am using `wget` it works normally as it was before I had set iptables

Comment: Is iptables running in the same place where you have the webserver? If so, those rules are never applied, you sould have something like

    iptables -N CUSTOMCHAIN
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j CUSTOMCHAIN
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j CUSTOMCHAIN